# как узнать ip адрес клиента которого пропускает через балансер

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

есть такая ситуация: у меня сервер my.qwe (192.168.0.1), который обращается к балансеру 192.168.0.2, который бросает клиента на 192.168.0.3 или 192.168.0.4. Я делаю запрос из машины 192.168.0.5. Вопрос: как узнать ip адрес моей машины. Примечание: использовал

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_COMING_FROM"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_VIA"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_COMING_FROM"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_FORWARDED"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_FROM"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["CLIENT_IP"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["FORWARDED"]
```

выдает или пустую сроку или ip балансера 192.168.0.2, что делать???